# How to locate and then click an image with pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Here is my code

```
import pyautogui
import sys
import time

button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('7boi.png')
pyautogui.move(button7location)
pyautogui.click(button7location)
```

Here is the error (sorry I just copied everything from the terminal
Windows PowerShell):

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

    PS C:\Users\rkwad> & 
    C:/Users/rkwad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
    c:/Users/rkwad/OneDrive/Desktop/python/moretest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\rkwad\OneDrive\Desktop\python\moretest.py", line 2, in <module>
        button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('7boi.png')
  File 
     
  "C:\Users\rkwad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
        packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
        return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File
     
   "C:\Users\rkwad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
       packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
        return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File 
    "C:\Users\rkwad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
   packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 372, in locateOnScreen
        retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File 
    "C:\Users\rkwad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
    packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 352, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File 
    "C:\Users\rkwad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
    packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 261, in _locateAll_python
        needleFileObj = open(needleImage, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    '7boi.png'
    PS C:\Users\rkwad>
```

What I am doing wrong? I have the image in a directory look
[its in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdeyF.png)

Comment: Your CWD is `C:\Users\rkwad`, not `c:/Users/rkwad/OneDrive/Desktop/python/` where the png file and the script are. Thus it cannot find it.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't really understand... what is a CWD? and how do I fix it so that it's in the right place

Comment: cwd -  current working directory. when you use just the file name, without path, it looks for it in CWD

Comment: so then how can i have it so that the image is in my cwd?

Comment: ok so i changed my code using what you said (I changed my folder name to testing code)

Comment: import pyautogui, sys, time
button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:\Users\rkwad\OneDrive\Desktop\TESTING CODE\ImageGrabs/7boi.png')
    pyautogui.move(button7location)
    pyautogui.click(button7location)

Comment: ok so now im getting this wierd error

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:/Users/rkwad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/rkwad/OneDrive/Desktop/TESTING CODE/moretest.py"
  File "c:\Users\rkwad\OneDrive\Desktop\TESTING CODE\moretest.py", line 2
    button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:\Users\rkwad\OneDrive\Desktop\TESTING CODE\ImageGrabs/7boi.png')
                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: do you know how to fix this?

Comment: On Windows don't use backalash in paths. use forward slash `'C:/Users/rkwad/OneDrive/Desktop/TESTING CODE/ImageGrabs/7boi.png'` or raw-string, e.g. `r'C:\Users\rkwad\OneDrive\Desktop\TESTING CODE\ImageGrabs\7boi.png'` or escape the backslash